# What does "this" refer to in the following javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

*DISCLAIMER:* I am asking about a specific use of `this`, not what `this` is used for in general. So, please no google/copy/paste speed answers (:

I have the javascript/jquery code below:

```
var req = {};

function getData()
{
    var fromPage = 0;
    var toPage = 1;

    req = $.ajax({
                    url: "/_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "xml",
                    data: xmlData,
                    complete: onSuccess,
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert("error: " + xhr.statusText);
                        alert(thrownError);
                    },
                    contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
                });

     req.fromPage = fromPage;
     req.toPage = toPage;
}

function onSuccess(resp) {
    alert(this.fromPage);
}
```

I find it pretty confusing that the code is using `fromPage` in two places (sorry not my code).

Does `this` refer to the var declared inside of `getData` or the one that is part of the `req` object? Or maybe something else entirely....

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `}, 50);` seems out of place there...

Comment: I'm getting a little confused by the syntax of the function declaration being followed by ", 50);" Is there an extra set of braces and closing parens in here?

Comment: @kingjiv, good catch.  Sorry, this is a simplified version of a larger chunk of code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) documentation:

> The this reference within all callbacks is the object in the context option passed to $.ajax in the settings; if context is not specified, this is a reference to the Ajax settings themselves.

In other words, since you didn't set the `context` option, `this` will be the options object `{...}` passed as the parameter to `$.ajax`.

The code you posted seems wrong: it reads `fromPage` from the wrong object. It would work if you set `fromPage` on the options object instead:

```
req = $.ajax({
    //other options here...
    fromPage: fromPage
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`onSuccess()` is being called from the `complete` handler in the context of the ajax request, which is being assigned to the `req` object, so `this` is that context - i.e. the `req` object, and fromPage is in fact `req.fromPage`

Comment: so `this` would be equal to `req` in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I belive `this` is refering to `req.fromPage` since that is the object that contains the called function.