# Using this keyword in XMLHttpRequest callback

Tags: javascript, ajax

What is difference between using **this** keyword vs variable name in XMLHttpRequest callback?

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", encodeURI(uri), true);
req.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4) {
        req.onreadystatechange = null; //avoid memory leaks
        if (this.status == 200) {
            var res = JSON.parse(req.responseText).d;
            console.log(res);
        }
    }
};
req.send();
```

Can I just use **req** instead of **this**, like `if (req.readyState == 4)`?

Comment: Yes, you can use both. In this case, there is no [difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711064/javascript-object-literal-reference-in-own-keys-function-instead-of-this) (unless someone overwrites `req`)

Comment: @KunalPradhan: No, his `this` is not referring to a function.

Comment: Did you *try* it? What was the result?

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in `onreadystatechange` handler by default `this` refers to the `XMLHttpRequest` object itself.

So yes, you can use either `this` or `req`

Answer (score 0):

I myself have encountered this similar problem recently, but I extended it to more general case: which context does `this` resolved to in callback?

regard to 3 prevalent callback type: *setTimeout*, *XMLHttpRequest*, *DOM*

- I read from the doc for first type, *setTimeout*, `this` will resolved to *window* object
- for *XMLHttpRequest* situation, `this` will resolved to XMLHttpRequest object itself, https://stackoverflow.com/a/6542261/4730119 this link will give you a explain and here is my test, for which I GET requested *api.json*'s content is a plain simple object and successfully printed in console,  notice I used `this.responseText`, not like most book taught using XHR object `request.responseText`
  [image]
- and last for *DOM*, it's just like XHR, `this` will resolved to object for which the callback added

  ```js
  document.querySelector('input')
  .addEventListener('input', function(e){console.log(this)});
  // will print input object
  ```